# Postgresql compare two select result on the same table

Tags: postgresql

I compare results from two selects and get 1 or 0 as a final result.
Below query syntax is good but this query causes timeout.

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN (
            select count(*)  from order  where ordered_date > (NOW() - INTERVAL '120 minutes')  
            and order_ordered = current_date) >  
            (select count(*)/3  
                    from order  
                    where ordered_date > (NOW() - INTERVAL '2 days' - INTERVAL '120 minutes')  
                    and ordered_date < (NOW() - INTERVAL '2 days')) 
        THEN 1 ELSE 0 end);
```

Therefore, i try to optimize the query to use an alias for each select as below :

```
select (case when a > b then 1 else 0 end) from (select count(*)  from order  where ordered_date > (NOW() - INTERVAL '120 minutes')  
            and order_ordered = current_date) as a,
            from (select count(*)/3  
                    from order  
                    where ordered_date > (NOW() - INTERVAL '2 days' - INTERVAL '120 minutes')  
                    and ordered_date < (NOW() - INTERVAL '2 days'))as b;
```

I have syntax error near "from", in my memory this kind of syntax works on mysql.
Could you please advise me if there a possiblity to use two times of "from" by using alias on Postgresql or if you know another possility i am a taker.

Sample:

First query gives : `select count(*)  from order  where ordered_date > (NOW() - INTERVAL '120 minutes') and order_ordered = current_date` -> 60

Seconde query gives : `select count(*)/3 from order where ordered_date > (NOW() - INTERVAL '2 days' - INTERVAL '120 minutes')  and ordered_date < (NOW() - INTERVAL '2 days')` -> 20

Final condition : case when (60 > 20 then 1 else 0 end)

Result expected : 1

Thanks

Comment: You can't just take MySQL syntax and use it in a Postgres query.  Beyond this, it would greatly help your question to include sample input data along with the desired output.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, i added more explanation. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using `SELECT in WITH` ([here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/queries-with.html) documentation).

```sql
WITH orders_current_date AS (
    SELECT count(*)
    FROM order
    WHERE ordered_date > (NOW() - INTERVAL '120 minutes')  
          AND order_ordered = current_date)
), orders_interval AS (
    SELECT count(*)/3
    FROM order
    WHERE ordered_date > (NOW() - INTERVAL '2 days' - INTERVAL '120 minutes')  
          AND ordered_date < (NOW() - INTERVAL '2 days')
)
SELECT
       CASE
           WHEN SELECT * FROM orders_current_date > SELECT * FROM orders_interval
                THEN '1'
           ELSE 
                0
       END;
```